# Importation of Master data with standard validation pt2

Tags: c#, excel

**How to combine this ideas?**

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string name = "Sheet1";
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection())
        {
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls" :
                    string xlsconStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                    con.ConnectionString = xlsconStr;
                break;

                case ".xlsx":
                    string xlsxconStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
                    con.ConnectionString = xlsxconStr;
                break;
            }

        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand oconn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + name + "$]", con))
        {
            con.Open();

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
}
```

**AND THIS**

```
Excel.Application myExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbooks myExcelWorkbooks;
Excel.Workbook myExcelWorkbook;

myExcelApp.Visible = false;
myExcelWorkbooks = myExcelApp.Workbooks;
string fileName = Convert.ToString("C:\\Users\\ProgrammerPC1\\Desktop\\DLAV FILES\\ACSAD.xls");
myExcelWorkbook = myExcelWorkbooks.Open(fileName);
Excel.Worksheet myExcelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
            //myExcelWorksheet.Select(Type.Missing);

foreach(Worksheet worksheet in myExcelWorkbook.Worksheets)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(worksheet.Name);
}
```

My idea is to remove the **dataGridView** and when ever I click the button (import) it will show **openFileDialog** > choose **Excel File** > at **listView** all ***SHEETS*** of a excel file will in the list.

Comment: Why did you tag `vb.net` if it is c#?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, just put them together!

You need to pick the `open file dialog` part and merge it with the `for each loop` as follow:

```
private string GetFileExcel()
{
    ExcelFileDialog.Filter = "File Excel|*.xls; *.xlsx";
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
    if (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return OpenFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
}
```

Now we call it inside the second snippet!

```
Excel.Application myExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbooks myExcelWorkbooks;
Excel.Workbook myExcelWorkbook;

myExcelApp.Visible = false;
myExcelWorkbooks = myExcelApp.Workbooks;

myExcelWorkbook = myExcelWorkbooks.Open(GetFileExcel()); //We call the new function here, inside the open
Excel.Worksheet myExcelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

foreach(Worksheet wSheet in myExcelWorkbook.Worksheets)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(wSheet.Name);
}
```

Now when you click on the button it will show the file dialog, and when you chose a file excel it will show it inside the list view!

Comment: sorry but i don't get this

Comment: public string filename { get; set; } 
what will I put here?

Comment: @Qwerty what do you mena with _i don't get this_

Comment: nevermind, now my problem is by clicking the first item on listBox which is coming from excel files sheet name it should populate the dataGridView

Comment: @Qwerty is your problem described inside your new question on stackoverflow?

Comment: Yes [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307432/error-the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized)

Comment: @Qwerty I gave you an answer on it

Comment: yes, but I used other code and now I want to export data from excel worksheet to datagrid

Comment: @Qwerty I did it, look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307432/error-the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized)